# Jquery Ajax Posting json to webserver (API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, api

Im trying to post with ajax to a json file (API) on a server. On stage Im dragging around two Kineticjs shapes, and when I stop dragging the shapes I wanna be able to save the new x and y coordinates to a json file on the server.
The problem is that I can not write like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'x': '(this).getPosition().x', 'y': '(this).getPosition().y' })
```

The errors I get is: 
Passed variable is not an array or object in.
Invalid query: update T_ZigbeeNodes set x=(, y=(, plan=( where ID=''
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' y=(, plan=( where ID=''' at line 1.

```
    var getIthData = $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://192.168.8.143/api/v11/plan/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'x': '(this).getPosition().x', 'y': '(this).getPosition().y' }),

        success: function(resultData) {

            alert("Post x coord and y coord and Plan, Complete!");
        }
    });
    getIthData.error(function() {

        alert("Something went wrong. Cant Post x coord and y coord and Plan");
    });
```

Can somebody give me a hint on how to solve the problem?

Comment: don't put the (this).getPosition().x in quotes. Same with the second call for the y.

Comment: @aaronfrost Hi, Ok, I understand. But I get the same errors know...

Answer (score 1):

```
'(this).getPosition().x'
```

This will add the string `(this).getPosition().x` to the json. To get the x and y values, remove the quotes :

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'x': (this).getPosition().x, 'y': (this).getPosition().y })
```

Comment: Then there is some problem with your query. Can you post the exact error and the sql you are using. 
Your original error `... set x=(, y=(, plan=( where ID='' ...` was taking the 1st `(` from `(this).getPosition().x` and adding it in the query as the value of x and y.

Comment: Ok, here is the json file on the server:
[{"e3014":{"name":"e3014","interval":15,"x":"10","y":"10","plan":"1","added":"2013-06-26 19:40:27","type":"enddev"}},{"e3026":{"name":"e3026","interval":15,"x":"23","y":"10","plan":"1","added":"2013-06-26 15:51:30","type":"enddev"}},{"R2500":{"name":"R2500","interval":1,"x":"0","y":"0","plan":"0","added":"2013-11-28 14:03:20","type":null}},{"R2502":{"name":"R2502","interval":1,"x":"0","y":"0","plan":"0","added":"2013-11-28 14:19:20","type":null}}]

Comment: In your PHP endpoint, can you set a breakpoint to see if the JSON object that you passed it is correct? If the JSON is formatted correct, then this is a PHP or SQL problem, not a JavaScript problem.

Comment: @aaronfrost Hmmmmmmm, Im not using PHP, and I dont know if JSON is formatted correct... That is what Im wondering, if the JSON is formatted correct.

Comment: jsonlint.com will tell you if your json is formatted correctly. Paste your json in there, and it will tell you.

Comment: Can you post the error you are currently getting? I doubt it is exactly same as the one in the OP.

Comment: If the JSON is value, then your problem is not a JavaScript problem, and you should likely ask your question in a different format.

Comment: @aaronfrost OK, but of course is the JSON file on the server OK/Valid, I know Its working... The problem is this line of code: data: JSON.stringify({ 'x': (this).getPosition().x, 'y': (this).getPosition().y }), something is written wrong... Posting in right formate, Its the problem... But thanks anyway...

Comment: @MrToniWP Check the SQL that is actually getting executed and you will find you root cause.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to 'Jquery Ajax Posting json to webserver (API)'

```
var data = [];
var name = this.getName();
var obj = {};
var position = this.getPosition();
var x = ( position.x < 0 ) ? 0 : position.x;
var y = ( position.y < 0 ) ? 0 : position.y;

obj[name] = {

    'name': name,
    'x': position.x,
    'y': position.y,
    'plan': 1
};

data.push( obj );
data = JSON.stringify( data );

var getIthData = $.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://192.168.8.143/api/v11/plan/',
    data: data

}).success( function( resultData)  {

    alert("Post name + x coord + y coord and Plan, Complete!");
}).error(function() {

    alert("Something went wrong. Cant Post name + x coord + y coord and Plan");
});
```